# Fragment onPause is called twice

Tags: android-fragments, sharedpreferences, onpause

```
I/System.out: {"status":"Checked in"}
I/System.out: onPause
I/System.out: {"status":"Never checked in"}
I/System.out: onPause
```

What I want was to save some data into a json file in a fragment when onPause() is called using the sharedPreference. It failed and when I tried to find out the reason why, I printed the json object using the following codes:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("onPause");
    /* some more codes */
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("FILENAME", ret.toString());
    System.out.println(ret.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Any way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using super.onPause(); in the method, remove it the first line

Comment: Some methods, such as View#onDetachedFromWindow, require that you also call the super implementation as part of your method.